# The "Haskell way" to extract/cumulate results inside an predefined vistor pattern iterator

Tags: haskell, state-monad, io-monad

I'm getting started with Haskell (from many years of C and c++) and have decided to attempt a small database project. I'm using a predefined binder library to a C database library (Database.kyotocabint). I'm struggling to get my head round how to do anything with the iterator interfaces due to the separation of effects when using a pre-defined method.

The toy demo to iterate over the data base and print it out (which works fine) is

```
test7 = do
  db <- openTree "testdatabase/mydb.kct" defaultLoggingOptions (Writer [] [])
  
  let visitor = \k v -> putStr (show k) >> putStr ":" >> putStrLn (show v) >> 
                        return (Left NoOperation)
  iterate db visitor False
  
  close db
```

Where iterate and visitor are provided by the library bindings and the relevant types are

```
iterate :: forall db. WithDB db => db -> VisitorFull -> Writable -> IO ()
visitor :: ByteString -> ByteString -> IO (Either VisitorAction b)
```

But I can't see to how extract information out from inside the iterator rather than process each one individually - for example collect all the keys beginning with 'a' in a list or even just count the number of entries.

Am I limited because iterate just has the type IO () and so I can't build in side effects and would have to rebuild this replacing the library versions? The state monad on paper seems to adress this but the visitor type doesn't seem to allow me to maintain the state over subsequent visitor calls.

What would be the Haskell way to solve this ?

Matthew

Edit - many thanks for the clear answer below which siad both 0 its not the Haskell way but also provided a solution - this answer led me to  [Mutable objects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Mutable_objects) which I found a clear explanation of the options.

Comment: It looks like the bindings library is "mid-level": it probably provides only little more than the direct translation of the C API, while one would like to have a richer API, e.g. to collect some information during the iteration as you are trying to do. With this limited API, I can't see any way to achieve what you want except by using some `IORef`s in your visitor -- there are akin to mutable variables in imperative programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kyotocabinet` library unfortunately does not seem to support your operation. Beyond `iterate`, it should expose some similar operation which returns something more complex than `IO ()`, say `IO a` or `IO [a]` while requiring a more complex `visitor` function.

Still, since we work inside `IO`, there is a workaround: we can exploit `IORef`s and collect results. I want to stress, though, that this is *not* idiomatic code one would write in Haskell, but something one is forced to use because if the limitation of this library.

Anyway, the code would look something like this (untested):

```
test7 = do
  db <- openTree "testdatabase/mydb.kct" defaultLoggingOptions (Writer [] [])
  w <- newIORef []   -- create mutable var, initialize to []
  let visitor = \k v -> do
         putStrLn (show k ++ ":" ++ show v)
         modifyIORef w ((k,v):)  -- prepend (k,v) to the list w
         return (Left NoOperation)
  iterate db visitor False
  result <- readIORef w   -- get the whole list
  print result
  
  close db
```

Since you come from C++, you might want to compare the code above to the following pseudo-C++:

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> w;
db.iterate([&](int k, int v) {
   std::cout << k << ", " << v << "\n";
   w.push_back({k,v});
});
// here we can read w, even if db.iterate returns void
```

Again, this is not something I would consider idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: HI - Thats really helpful thank you - knowing that it is not my limited undestanding of language but a consequence of the foriegn funciton implementation is very useful. Getting used to what is trivial in C not being trivial or even possible in Haskell is probbaly my biggest challenge at the moment

Comment: add a hint as to what would be the idiomatic haskell approach, perhaps?

Comment: @WillNess That would depend on an API that the library does not currently export.

Comment: yes, you say this in the answer already, :) but what could that be if it had it? the general outline, a few words.... a mention of some other library that does it.... a hint, so a casual reader gets a glimpse of understanding... would be great. :) what would the library had to export so we could write such a code, maybe?

Comment: @MatthewClemence In Haskell it is a common trend to exploit types to _constrain_ what code can do. In general, we like having code like `map f list` and know that `f` can not have any side effect, and can only read one list element at a time. For those cases where we can't work with such restrictions, e.g. we do need to print within `f`, we resort to other library routines, e.g. `traverse`. In principle we could use `IO` everywhere and be something vaguely like Java, but we strive to avoid that when possible, and provide static constraints on the code behavior.

Comment: I'm guessing that the solution would actually be - create a new IO iteration function which in parallel can carry a result (IO, a) and use the lower level interfaces to the database - for example there are cursors and access functions. Then once processed on the result a return just the IO action for chaining ? I'm going to try somthing like that as i'm interested on the relative preformance of the two methods.

Comment: @MatthewClemence The most typical Haskell solution would be to be polymorphic in the choice of return type. For instance, instead of working in `IO`, work in an arbitrary instance of `MonadIO`, updating the `Visitor` alias and the types of functions using it as appropriate. This would let you choose the return type to carry whatever additional information you want.